# Exponents of powers in cyclotomic extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, fields, number-fields

For every number field $K$ and for every $a \in K$ let $$\epsilon(K;a) := \sup\!\left\{e \in \mathbb{N} : \exists b \in K \text{ such that } a = b^e\right\}. $$
Now let $K$ be a number field and let $a \in K$ such that $\epsilon(K;a)$ is finite.

- Is $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \epsilon(K(\zeta_n);a)$ finite?
- Can $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \epsilon(K(\zeta_n);a)$ be effectively bounded in terms of $K$ and $a$ ? (Here $\zeta_n$ is a $n$th primitive root of unity.)
- Can the $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon(K(\zeta_n);a) > \epsilon(K;a)$ be effectively determined?

Comment: Is it even true that if $\epsilon(K;a)$ is finite, then so is the supremum in the first question?

Comment: @Wojowu I meant to implicity ask it in the first question but, after your comment, I added it as a separate question

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: A positive answer shoud follow from the fact that the Galois group of $X^e-a$ is usually a non-abelian semidirect product, while $\zeta_n$ generates an abelian extension.